# No qualifying bean for autowired JPA repository in JUnit test in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, junit, h2

I have several repositories extending `JpaRepository`. Now I want to test the custom queries I added in a unit test using a real instance of an H2 database (not in-memory - so that I can inspect the database using the web console).

However, auto-wiring the repository in the unit does not work, I always get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ... UserRepository available`.

The code of the repository and the unit test is listed below. Thanks for any help!

UserRepository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

UserRepositoryTests

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    @Commit
    public void test() throws AESEncryptionException {
        User user = new User().setFirstName("ABC").setLastName("XYZ");
        user = userRepository.save(user);
        assertNotNull(user.getId());
    }

}
```

TestConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:/application.properties")
public class TestConfiguration {}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:file:./db/app-data
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.h2.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others = true
```

**EDIT**:
As suggested by Mensur Qulami, removing `@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)` did the trick, since this is already covered by `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Does the package that contains `TestConfiguration` includes `UserRepository` class as well? Because, if I am not mistaken, `@ComponentScan` by default, starts from its base class.

Comment: No, thanks for the hint. I specified the `basePackages` parameter of the `@ComponentScan` annotation. But now the actual test is not executed ... .

Comment: Can you share the current error?

Comment: There is no error, the log is simply `Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.` and the JUnit test is not even started.

Comment: Change the name of `UserRepository`, Spring already has one, I think. Or you can utilize `@Qualifier` with another name for your bean, since it says there are more than one interface available

Comment: Nothing changed. I have another repository in the project, i think this explains the 2 repositories found.

Comment: What could be the reason that a test is not executed?

Comment: What is interesting for me is that, if Spring application context is loaded, then how you don't see any other log. I mean at least you have so see some, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195926/discussion-between-jakob-benz-and-mensur-qulami).

Answer (score 2):

You could use *DataJpaTest* in combination with *@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)* to use your 'real' database

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest (showSql = true )
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class UserRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    ....
```

Comment: Tried it, but now the test is not executed, the last log that is shown is `Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 2 repository interfaces.`, and then nothing happens.

Comment: did should work, I guess there is some other configuration problem.